# Angular and asp.net core API showing error during Image Uploading

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I am new in angular and asp.net core api. Without Image the data saved successfully but when I add image then it showing error

This is my Controller

```
public async Task<ActionResult<Products>> PostProducts([FromForm]Products products)
    {
        products.ThumbnailImage = await SaveImage(products.ImageFile);
        
        _context.Products.Add(products);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return CreatedAtAction("GetProducts", new { id = products.Id }, products);
    }

    [NonAction]
    public async Task<string> SaveImage(IFormFile imageFile)
    {
        string imageName = new String(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(imageFile.FileName).Take(10).ToArray()).Replace(' ', '-');
        imageName = imageName + DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmssfff") + Path.GetExtension(imageFile.FileName);
        var imagePath = Path.Combine(_env.ContentRootPath, "Images", imageName);
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(imagePath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            await imageFile.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
        }
        return imageName;
    }
```

And This is my AddProductFormComponent.ts File

```
onSubmit(form: NgForm){
if(this.service.Product.id==0)
this.insertProduct(form);
else
this.updateProduct(form);
}

insertProduct(form: NgForm){
this.service.postProduct().subscribe(
  res => {
    this.resetForm(form);
    this.service.getProductList();
    this.toastr.success('Added Successfully', 'Product');
  },
  error => {console.log(error);}
);
}

updateProduct(form: NgForm){
if(confirm('Do you want to update this record?')){
  this.service.putProduct().subscribe(
    res => {
      this.resetForm(form);
      this.service.getProductList();
      this.toastr.success('Updated Successfully', 'Product');
    },
    error => {console.log(error);}
  );
 }
 }

resetForm(form: NgForm){
 form.form.reset();
 this.service.Product = new Product();
}
```

And This is my HTML File

```
<mat-card>
<form autocomplete="off" #form="ngForm" (submit)="onSubmit(form)" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="id" [value]="service.Product.id"/>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="name">Product Name</label>
  <input class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name="name" #name="ngModel"
  [(ngModel)]="service.Product.name" required
  [class.invalid]="name.invalid && name.touched"/>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="price">Price</label>
  <input class="form-control" placeholder="Price" name="price" #price="ngModel"
  [(ngModel)]="service.Product.price" required
  [class.invalid]="price.invalid && price.touched"/>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="previousPrice">previousPrice</label>
  <input class="form-control" placeholder="previousPrice" name="previousPrice" #previousPrice="ngModel"
  [(ngModel)]="service.Product.previousPrice" required
  [class.invalid]="previousPrice.invalid && previousPrice.touched"/>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="thumbnailImage">Image</label>
  <input type="file" accept="image/*" class="form-control" placeholder="Image" name="thumbnailImage" #thumbnailImage="ngModel"
  [(ngModel)]="service.Product.thumbnailImage" required
  [class.invalid]="thumbnailImage.invalid && thumbnailImage.touched"/>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="description">Description</label>
  <input class="form-control" placeholder="description" name="description" #description="ngModel"
  [(ngModel)]="service.Product.description" required
  [class.invalid]="description.invalid && description.touched"/>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="categories">Category</label>
  <select class="form-control" name="categories" #categories="ngModel"
  [(ngModel)]="service.Product.catId">
  <option [value]="ct.catId" *ngFor="let ct of Catservice.ProductCategoryList" >{{ct.catName}}</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="brand">Brand</label>
  <select class="form-control" name="brand" #brand="ngModel"
  [(ngModel)]="service.Product.brandId">
  <option [value]="brand.brandId" *ngFor="let brand of Brandservice.ProductBrandList" >{{brand.brandName}}</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="isAbailable">Available</label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="isAbailable" #isAbailable="ngModel"
  [(ngModel)]="service.Product.isAbailable"
  [class.invalid]="isAbailable.invalid && isAbailable.touched"/>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <button class="btn btn-info btn-block" [disabled]="form.invalid" type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
</div>
 </form>
 </mat-card>
```

Now When I am submitting this form. I am getting this error

> HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 500, statusText: "OK", url: "https://localhost:44328/api/Products", ok: false, …}error: "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.\r\n   at MyMymensinghAPI.Controllers.ProductsController.SaveImage(IFormFile imageFile) in E:\Angular\mymymensingh\MyMymensinghAPI\MyMymensinghAPI\Controllers\ProductsController.cs:line 105\r\n   at MyMymensinghAPI.Controllers.ProductsController.PostProducts(Products products) in E:\Angular\mymymensingh\MyMymensinghAPI\MyMymensinghAPI\Controllers\ProductsController.cs:line 87\r\n   at lambda_method67(Closure , Object )\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location ---\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)\r\n   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)\r\n   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)\r\n\r\nHEADERS\r\n=======\r\nAccept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br\r\nAccept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9\r\nConnection: close\r\nContent-Length: 168\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\nHost: localhost:44328\r\nReferer: http://localhost:4200/\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36\r\nsec-ch-ua: " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="91", "Chromium";v="91"\r\nsec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0\r\norigin: http://localhost:4200\r\nsec-fetch-site: cross-site\r\nsec-fetch-mode: cors\r\nsec-fetch-dest: empty\r\n"headers: HttpHeaderslazyInit: () => {…}lazyUpdate: nullnormalizedNames: Map(0) {}**proto**: Objectmessage: "Http failure response for https://localhost:44328/api/Products: 500 OK"name: "HttpErrorResponse"ok: falsestatus: 500statusText: "OK"url: "https://localhost:44328/api/Products"**proto**: HttpResponseBase

Please Help me to upload image

Comment: You have null in your code. Just debug it

Comment: Does your service handle `multipart/form-data`  or it is just sending the object?

Comment: this is my service: - constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  readonly baseURL='https://localhost:44328/api/Products';
  Product: Product = new Product();
  ProductList: Product[];

  getProductList(){
    this.http.get(this.baseURL)
    .toPromise()
    .then(res => this.ProductList = res as Product[]);
  }

  postProduct(){
    return this.http.post(this.baseURL,this.Product);
  }

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of data that we don't need.
And what we need is the code of the service, and that's not there.

You get a null-reference on your

> .SaveImage(IFormFile imageFile)

because it looks like your not sending anything at all from angular.

At some point you would expect something like the following to catch the imagefile-data.

```
const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('Imagefile', this.selectedFile, this.selectedFile.name);
```

and consequently pass it on as an argument in your http-request, like e.g.

```
 this.apiClient.uploadImageFile(formData)
            .subscribe((res: any) => (this.uploadOrDeleteResults = res),
                (error) => {                   
                    this.errorHttpErrorResponse = error;
                    this.errors = this.errorHttpErrorResponse.error;
                },
                () => {
                    this.toastr.success("image upload succesfull");
                    this.resetForm();
                })
```

and a client acting like this

```
 uploadImageFile(formdata: FormData): Observable<any> {       
            const getUrl = `${this.apiUrl}/UploadImageFile`;
            return this.httpClient.post(getUrl, formdata)
                .pipe(map(response => response));};
```

We'll we don't actually know what happens in the service, because that code wasn't shared, but both

```
this.service.putProduct().subscribe(
    res => {
```

as

```
this.service.postProduct().subscribe(
  res => {
```

do not seem to pass on the actuel image file data. Hence a null reference on your controller.

In order to solve the issue, please submit your code of the service you've written, or better, provide a github link so we can test and try the code.

Take care, be well and good luck.